Identify 80s TV movie about a singing girl & her disabled father
I saw a movie when I was younger (I'm 35 now). I believe it was a TV movie in the 80's about a girl & her father. The father is either a paraplegic or a quadriplegic & the only part that I really remember is at one point in the movie, the girl sings "Through the Eyes of Love". I'm thinking it was a family drama of some sort & I realize how very little information I remember about the movie... but this has been bugging me for years, every time I hear that song. Can anybody help?!?

A better title would be "Identify 80s movie about a singing girl & her father".  There is probably also an 'identify' tag that can be applied.

The movie you're thinking of is Quiet Victory: The Charlie Wedemeyer Story (1988), starring Michael Nouri and Pam Dawber.  
It is a true story about a football coach and his battle with ALS. (And his struggle to raise a teenage daughter which results in her singing "Through the Eyes of Love" to him at a ceremony in his honor.)  I haven't seen the movie but once in the late 80s or early 90s, but I remember it was good. And it made me cry. I hope you're able to hunt it down.

Though, this movie has nothing to do with a paraplegic or quadriplegic father, it does involve a father and a daughter. The plot is about a girl, who is a gifted figure skater, meets an accident, loses her eyes, then with the help of her father, coach, and a guy she falls in love with, retrains. 
The song Through the eyes of love was theme song of this movie, and was made famous by this movie.
The movie is 1978 family drama, Ice Castles. Could this be, what you're looking for?
